# rforcecom.getObjectDescription does not work with certain salesforce objects

Tags: r, salesforce

When attempting to obtain the descriptions of a list of objects from salesforce using rforcecom.getObjectDescription for certain objects I get the error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

The error occours if I run the function within a loop or outside of it. I have not been able to find any reason why some objects work and others do not and I do not understand what the error message is trying to convey.

Does anyone know how to solve or workaround this error? If not is there a way to tell which objects will cause the error and which will not?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not a hundred percent sure about "rforcecom" package. But Salesforce metadata data API doesn't support all objects. [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/55) provides a list of all compatible and non-compatible objects.

If you are passing the object names in loop, you might want to filter out the objects which are not compatible from the loop collection.